# Helper to translate multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to make a helper that takes multiple values related to a User and translate them and return them as a string to my view.

I was thinking about something like this:

in the helper:

```
def interests(user)
  @all_interests = user.interests
  @all_interests.each_with_index do |interest|
    t('user.#{interest}') + ", "
    if index == @all_interests.size - 1
      t('user.#{interest}') + "."
    end
  end
```

In the view:

```
<p> My interests are: <%= interests(@user) %> </p>
```

The desired result would be for example:

> My interests are: Engineering, Sports, Gardening.

But at this moment it returns an array like following:

> My interests are: ["Engineering", "Sports", "Gardening"]

Edit: All the values are correctly translated in my i18n file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the results and join them with a ', ' in your case:

```
def interests(user)
  user.interests.map {|interest| t("user.#{interest}") }.join(', ')
end
```

BTW, there is no need to set an instance variable. The helper method is returning the result already.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to get me one step ahead, although, it still doesnt seem to pass the correct value to the translation
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.user.#{interest}">#{Interest}</span>

Comment: Double quotes should be used for string interpolation to work

Comment: I forgot to mention but please take a look at the `.to_sentence` method, you can specify the connector and make it more human readable and translatable. For example: `%w(a b c).to_sentence #=> a, b, and c`

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Vasfed

Comment: Thank you, this worked, and thank you for the tip on the .to_sentence, although that kind of overrules the purpose of using this method for translations since the "and" it adds will not change based on locales I assume?

Comment: You assume wrong: `%w(a b c).to_sentence(last_word_connector: t( ' and '))`. Of course `' and '` could have it's own translation.  See the documentation for the other options you can pass.

Answer (score 1):

Better use array map+join:

```
def interests(user)
  user.interests.map{|i| t("user.#{i}")}.join(', ')
end
```

And in view:

```
<p> My interests are: <%= interests(@user) %>. </p>
```